# How to auto ordering ID in a database table after adding a new row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

Suppose I have a database table `services` with some data like `A`(id=1), `D`(id=2), `F`(id=3), `L`(id=4), `M`(id=5) in MySQL.

Now I want to insert another service `B` inside that `service` table after `A` and also want to auto order of the other data `id`.

So the new data of `service` table is `A`(id=1), `B`(id=2), `D`(id=3), `F`(id=4), `L`(id=5), `M`(id=6)

How to do it?

Comment: Is id an auto_increment column?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @P.Salmonyes ... auto incremented

Comment: @OTTA...cause we have already inserted some data in that table...but now we need to add more data in that with an given order

Comment: In which case, it's not an auto id

Comment: You have no guarantee in what order a query will return data unless you explicitly sort it so the value of id doesn't matter, you sort on the field you want it ordered by.

Answer (score 0):

Use a MySQL variable.

If, for example, you have:

```
create table services (
  name varchar(10),
  id int
);

insert into services (name, id) values ('A', 1);
insert into services (name, id) values ('D', 2);
insert into services (name, id) values ('F', 3);
insert into services (name, id) values ('L', 4);
insert into services (name, id) values ('M', 5);
```

And then you insert a new row `B`:

```
insert into services (name, id) values ('B', null);
```

Then, you can update the ids using a variable:

```
set @newid = 0;
update services set id = (@newid := @newid + 1)
order by name;
```

Result:

```
name        id           
----------  --
A           1            
B           2            
D           3            
F           4            
L           5            
M           6
```